# Write a regex for url match

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm trying to write wordpress pretty permalinks regex.

I have following urls. I need 2 matches,

```
1st : last word between / and / before get/
2nd : string which is start with get/
```

Url's may be like these

http://localhost/akasia/yacht-technical-services/**yacht-crew**/**get/gulets/for/sale/**

Here I need "yacht-crew" and "get/gulets/for/sale/"

http://localhost/akasia/**testimonials**/**get/motoryachts/for/sale/**

here I need "testimonials" and get/motoryachts/for/sale/

http://localhost/akasia/may/be/lots/of/seperator/but/ineed/**last**/**get/ships/for/rent/**

here I need "last" and get/ships/for/rent/

I catch 2nd part with

> (.*(get/(.*)?))

but for first part there is no luck.

I will be appreciated if someone helps.

Regards
Deniz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
([^\/]+?)\/(get\/.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uN6yH3/1

The concept is that you match non-slash characters up to the first slash (non-greedy) that is followed by the word "get" grouping it, and then just grab the rest as the second group.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciated. It is working exacly how I want. I could not catch the pagename with wordpress. But regex is great. I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: Could you please help me to solve this one too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981710

Comment: @DenizPorsuk Sorry about that didn't see this in time.  I'm glad to see your second question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming PHP.

```
$path = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH);
$s = strrpos($path,'/');
$matches[] = substr($path,$s+1);
```

Comment: @Misundestood I appreciated. But I need to catch this from regex. I can run it only like add_rewrite_rule('(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?(.*(/get/(.*)?))', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]&get=$matches[3]', 'top');

Comment: I'm old, I didn't see at first what you were doing. Thought you already had the url.  And did not realize the url's would all be very consistent. I often will still use strpos instead of regex because it is usually faster and do not have to debug the regex expression. Regex makes nice concise code but as the complexity increase so does the execution time.

Comment: I aggree with that. Using strpos is better than regex. But this case wordpress does not allow to use strpos.