# Is it possible to make ineffective a character in regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm trying to write wordpress pretty permalinks regex.

I have following urls. I need 2 matches,

1st : last word between / and / before get/
2nd : string which is start with get/
Url's may be like these

http://localhost/akasia/yacht-technical-services/yacht-crew/get/gulets/for/sale/

Here I need "yacht-crew" and "get/gulets/for/sale/"

http://localhost/akasia/testimonials/get/motoryachts/for/sale/

here I need "testimonials" and get/motoryachts/for/sale/

http://localhost/akasia/may/be/lots/of/seperator/but/ineed/last/get/ships/for/rent/

here I need "last" and get/ships/for/rent/

```
$url1 = 'somepage/get/gulets/for/sale'; // I need somepage and get/gulets/for/sale
$url2 = 'somepage/subpage/get/motoryachts/for/rent'; // I need subpage and get/motoryachts/for/rent
$url3 = 'may/be/unlimited/directories/but/i/need/here/get/ships/for/sale'; // I need here and get/ships/for/sale
$url4 = 'services/get/gulets/for/sale'; // I need services and get/gulets/for/sale
$regex = '([^\/]+?)\/(get\/.+)';

// I can not change anything below.
preg_match("#^$regex#", $url4, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>"
```

I catch $url4 but Could not $url1, $url2, $url3

I appreciate if someone help.

Comment: it works https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/4

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you very much for help. But If you look at carrefully there is ^ at preg_march(^$regex) which I can not change. If you use like ^([^\/]+?)\/(get\/.+) it is only matching $url1. Not rest of them

Comment: yep, don't use `^` anchor because `^` asserts that we are at the start. I think you solved the problem by your own. I didn't notice the `^` anchor present in your `preg_match` call.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I do not use it like this way. Wordpress works like this. I can not change core files. I can use only hooks

Comment: try this https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/5

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you so much. Works great.. Appreciated. May I ask you one question more..

Comment: @AvinashRaj How can I catch all line before get/ like somepage, somepage/subpage, may/be/unlimited/directories/but/i/need/here?

Comment: did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/6 ?

Comment: (.*(get/(.*)?)) is solved my problem. But your regex is great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\K` to discard the previously matched characters from printing at the final.

```
.*(?:\/|^)\K([^\/]+?)\/(get\/.+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/5)